# when I write a music player with pygame, I have to write a loop to monitor the playing state?

Tags: python, pygame, playback

I write a music player with pygame, and I want play a track list, but I have to write a loop progame to monitor the playing state，but in this way the cpu usage is more than 100%,and sometimes no responding,how can I modify my code

```
 while 1:
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()!=1:
            listNumber+=1
            player(listNumber) #tell player program go to next song
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(music_stop_event)` and then check for that event in your event loop.

```
music_stop_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
```

(and in the event loop)

```
    events = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == music_stop_event:
            # do something
```

Comment: I have to write code like this  
    `events  = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:
        if event.type == SONG_END:
            itemlistNumber+=1
            nextsong(itemlistNumber)
    while 1:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()`  <br/> but not  `events = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == music_stop_event:
            # do something` <br/>or it not play, but if I write `while1` it soon to be no responding

Comment: sorry  I'm new in this stackoverflow, I can't use its code format form now